# Guess the number in React does not display message for correct answer

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and I tried to code the guess the number game. After following a few tutorials this is what I wrote

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [ans, setAns] = useState(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));

  const [results, setResults] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const trackGuesses = [];
  const [guesses, setGuesses] = useState(trackGuesses);

  const onChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
  function ResetGame() {
    setAns(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
  }

  function verify() {
    const userInput = value;
    console.log(ans);
    if (userInput === ans) {
      setResults(<p>Correct answer!</p>);
      ResetGame();
    } else if (userInput < ans) {
      setResults(<p>You guessed low!</p>);
      setGuesses((guesses) => [...guesses, userInput]);
    } else if (userInput > ans) {
      setResults(<p>You guessed high!</p>);
      setGuesses((guesses) => [...guesses, userInput]);
    }
  }
  return (
      <div className="App">
        Guess the number
        <p>Guess number between 1 to 10</p>
        <input value={value} type="number" onChange={onChange} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={verify}>
          GUESS
        </button>
        {results}
        <br />
        Your guesses till now:{" "}
        {guesses.map((guesses) => (
          <li>{guesses}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <App />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This works perfectly when the guessed number is high or low,  but for some reason, the message does not display when the answer is correct.

In the console you can see the correct answer, so when you type that the correct answer message does not show.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also in

```
{guesses.map((guesses) => (
          <li>{guesses}</li>
        ))}
```

I would like to display the elements in one line like this `Your guesses till now: 1,2,3` instead of showing in a list. How can I do that too?

Comment: Problem is at this line: `userInput === ans`. The left-side is a `string` and the right-side is a `number`. Using `===` to compare string & number results in falsy. Please try `+userInput === ans` & it should work.

Comment: Also to make the result comma separated you can use `guesses.toString()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison between `userInput` and `ans` fails because one is a `string` and other is a `number`. It has been fixed in snippet below.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [ans, setAns] = useState(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));

  const [results, setResults] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const trackGuesses = [];
  const [guesses, setGuesses] = useState(trackGuesses);

  const onChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
  function ResetGame() {
    setAns(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
  }

  function verify() {
    const userInput = value;
    console.log(ans);
    if (+userInput === ans) {
      setResults(<p>Correct answer!</p>);
      ResetGame();
    } else if (userInput < ans) {
      setResults(<p>You guessed low!</p>);
      setGuesses((guesses) => [...guesses, userInput]);
    } else if (userInput > ans) {
      setResults(<p>You guessed high!</p>);
      setGuesses((guesses) => [...guesses, userInput]);
    }
  }
  return (
      <div className="App">
        Guess the number
        <p>Guess number between 1 to 10</p>
        <input value={value} type="number" onChange={onChange} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={verify}>
          GUESS
        </button>
        {results}
        <br />
        Your guesses till now:{" " + guesses.join(', ')}
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <App />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- Prefix `+` to `userInput` transforms it to a `number` and then the comparison with `ans` yields the correct result.
- Instead of prefix `+`, other methods may also be used, including (but not limited to) `parseInt`.
- To render in same line: simply `.join` the `guesses` array with separator as `', '` and the result will be in a single line.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Because your `userInput` data type is `String` and `ans` data type is `integer` and you are comparing using `===` which compares value as well as type in javascript so you need to change type of `userInput` to `integer` as following. Keep other code as it is.

```
function verify() {
    const userInput = parseInt(value);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jsN00b suggested, you are comparing using `===` which check for types as well. Typecast one of them to be the same type as the other.

As for showing the guesses in a single line as `Your guesses till now: 1,2,3`, try below:

```css
.guessList > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="guessList">
    Your guesses till now:
    <li>1, </li>
    <li>2, </li>
    <li>3</li> 
</div>
```